# PHP regex to search across multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm using preg_* in PHP to search for the pattern `<!-- %{data=THIS GETS MATCHED}% -->` and pull out the matched text.

The pattern for this is:

```
preg_match('#<!-- %{' . $knownString . '\s*=\s*(.*?)}% -->#', ...)
```

What I would like it to do is search across multiple lines for the string. For example:

```
<!-- %{data=
THIS GETS
MATCHED AND
RETURNED
}% -->
```

How can I edit my current pattern to have this search ability?

Answer (score 6):

You should add "s" [pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), without it dot matches any character **except** for newline:

```
preg_match('#<!-- %{' . $knownString . '\s*=\s*(.*?)}% -->#s', ...)
```

Comment: I'd secure $knownString with preg_quote() before gluing it to the rest of the regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Does `preg_match('#<!-- %{' . $knownString . '\s*=\s*(.*?)}% -->#s', ...)` work?

I don't have PHP here at work atm so I can't test it...

Comment: I managed to get it working by using `/<!-- %{' . $knownString . '=\s*(.*?)}% -->/s`. I'm terrible at regex, however, so if you're looking at that thinking "...lol?". Please tell me xD

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
<?php
    $testString = "<!-- %{data=
THIS GETS
MATCHED AND
RETURNED
}% -->";
    $knownString = "data";
    preg_match( "@<!-- %\\{" . $knownString . "\\s*=\\s*([^\\}]+)\\}% -->@", $testString, $match );
    var_dump( $match );
?>
```

Returned:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(54) "<!-- %{data=
THIS GETS
MATCHED AND
RETURNED
}% -->"
  [1]=>
  string(34) "THIS GETS
MATCHED AND
RETURNED
"
}
```

Comment: `m`, or multiline mode, changes the meaning of the `^` and `$` anchors, enabling them to match at line boundaries as well as at the beginning and end of the string.  Your regex works because you changed the dot to `([^\\}]`; the `m` is irrelevant.